# Obstacle avoidance or wandering behaviour in gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo, teleoperation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am on ROS electric, I have used gazebo with erratic robot in teleoperation mode, however can I make my robot move in an spontaneous 'obstacle avoidance', 'wandering' or 'random walk' mode - without any keyboard/ joystick input ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12455/obstacle-avoidance-or-wandering-behaviour-in-gazebo/) by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1108 on 2011-12-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The ROS [navigation stack](http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation) is your best bet for autonomous navigation. It has obstacle avoidance built-in.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2011-12-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0